# How do I scroll in tmux?

Tags: tmux

How do I scroll with either the keyboard or mouse? The [`tmux`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html) man page indicates one must enter copy-mode to scroll. Is there a way to quickly scroll without manually entering copy-mode?

Comment: What overhead are you concerned with? `copy-mode` is the way to view history (and optionally copy stuff out of it).

Comment: for me you can press f7 for scroll mode and q to quit

Comment: `set -g mode-mouse on` per @chaiyachaiya's answer was the winner for me

Comment: Just run: `echo "set -g mouse on" >> ~/.tmux.conf` and you'll be able to scroll.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72147360/how-does-one-set-the-mouse-on-a-remote-hpc

Answer (score 2372, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> then <kbd>[</kbd> then you can use your normal navigation keys to scroll around (eg. <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>PgDn</kbd>). Press <kbd>q</kbd> to quit scroll mode.

Alternatively you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>PgUp</kbd> to go directly into copy mode and scroll one page up (which is what it sounds like you will want most of the time)

In `vi` mode (see below), you can also scroll the page up/down line by line using <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd> (if you're already in scroll mode). Unshifted, the cursor moves instead of the page.

Excerpts from the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tmux):

> tmux may be controlled from an attached client by using a key combination of a prefix key, ‘C-b’ (Ctrl-b) by default, followed by a command key.

```
 The default command key bindings are:

[           Enter copy mode to copy text or view the history.

Function                     vi              emacs
--------                     --              -----
Half page down               C-d             M-Down
Half page up                 C-u             M-Up
Next page                    C-f             Page down
Previous page                C-b             Page up
Scroll down                  C-Down or C-e   C-Down
Scroll up                    C-Up or C-y     C-Up
Search again                 n               n
Search again in reverse      N               N
Search backward              ?               C-r
Search forward               /               C-s
```

Plus a bunch more. Note that you have to press `C-b` twice if you use that for page up since `C-b` is bound as the command key. See the man page for information on prefacing a copy mode command with a repeat count.

You can set the key binding mode using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd>, then

```
:set-window-option mode-keys emacs
```

or `vi`.

Comment: I think `C-b =` is `choose-buffer` by default. Did you mean `C-b [` (which is `copy-mode` by default)? Also you can also use `C-b PageUp` to start copy-mode directly on the previous page (very handy when you know what you want to view/copy has already scrolled off the current page).

Comment: @Chris: In my tmux 0.8 (and its man page), `C-b =` is `scroll-mode`. [Apparently](http://tmux.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tmux/tmux/CHANGES), newer versions have dropped that.

Comment: Ahh, that explains it. I think I started with 1.1 which was already after `scroll-mode` had been subsumed. The OP says ‘only two instances of the word "scroll" [in the man page]’, so the version is probably one without `scroll-mode`.

Comment: Correct, my tmux has no scroll-mode. You need to `C-b [` to enter copy mode and then use either the emacs or vi key-bindings to scroll around. This seems like a lot of steps just to scroll, but the benefits of tmux still outweigh these annoyances. I'm on a macbook and there is no PageUp key :-\. (Also, how do I make keys with markdown like you did, Dennis?)

Comment: @chadoh: Try these on your Macbook: Home: fn-LeftArrow; End: fn-RightArrow; Page Up: fn-UpArrow; Page Down: fn-DownArrow.  To make keycaps: `<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`

Comment: on macbook, the fn+up goes straight to terminal app and never hits tmux

Comment: On a macbook if you're in scroll mode you can use fn+Shift+LeftArrow to scroll up a page.

Comment: With vi mode-keys you can also use it's typical: C-y and C-e to scroll up/down line by line

Comment: @chaiyachaiya's answer is much better (If you can bear to reach for the mouse)

Comment: To escape from scroll mode, press Escape or Q. Don't get stuck like I did :)

Comment: Isn't there a better way than just up and down arrows to scroll tmux? Like batch scrolling as in ctrl+b similar to VIM?

Comment: @CharlieParker: I've expanded my answer to include some navigation key bindings. Note that you can use numeric count prefixes like you would in `vim` so (set to vi key bindings) you could press `2` then `PageUp` (or `Ctrl-b` (twice)) and you'd move up two screen fulls.

Comment: So much hassle just to accomplish basic stuff - why UI has to be so poor?

Comment: Is `Shift-j` and `Shift-k` line by line scrolling enabled by default? It seems like it is on my machine.

Comment: @mbigras: It seems to be.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson does that mean tmux is in vi mode by default? Or does it only have some of the functionality? Line by line scrolling in this case.

Comment: @mbigras: From the man page: "mode-keys [vi | emacs]
                     Use vi or emacs-style key bindings in copy mode.  The
                     default is emacs, unless VISUAL or EDITOR contains
                     'vi'."

Comment: @DennisWilliamson thank you! Makes sense, `$echo $EDITOR #=> vim` what did you search for in the man page? For example, `:/foobar`

Comment: @mbigras I searched for "mode-keys" and looked around.

Comment: To escape, type in `Q` or `Ctrl` + `J`.

Comment: `CTRL-B` and then `PgUp` is working fine. Then I can use `PgUp`, `PgDn` or `ArrUp`, `ArrDn`. To leave and auto scroll to the end hit `Esc`

Comment: I know this is sort of against the spirit but I want to use my mouse...

Comment: @CharlieParker: https://gist.github.com/paulodeleo/5594773 (I haven't tested this)

Comment: Keyboard short cuts for more: https://tmuxcheatsheet.com/

Comment: Does anybody know how one can memorize this?

Answer (score 530):

Well, you should consider the proper way to set scrolling:
add in your `~/.tmux.conf`

```
set -g mouse on        #For tmux version 2.1 and up
```

or

```
set -g mode-mouse on   #For tmux versions < 2.1
```

It worked for me in windows and panes. Now tmux is just perfect.

[Practical tmux](https://mutelight.org/practical-tmux) has more info on tmux.conf files.

Comment: When I do this, mouse clicks and scrolls cause gibberish characters to be printed to the prompt area of the terminal I'm using with tmux. Any ideas?

Comment: This works great for me. Now if only we can figure key bindings to do the same (maybe a screen at a time), I'll be a very happy camper.

Comment: Future tmux mouse users: To save you having to scroll to the bottom again before typing, you can hit `q` to exit scroll mode.

Comment: Mouse scrolling works fine with this, but unfortunately I cannot use the mouse to select text anymore. Using Tilda and tmux.

Comment: Important note: This setting breaks highlighting and copying text. Use shift+click to maintain this functionality.

Comment: @Mr.F try `set mouse-utf8 off`

Comment: 1) we can no longer select text using clicks
2) we can't scroll into vim

Comment: This worked for me, but only after killing the tmux server with `tmux kill-server`.

Comment: @pltrdy @friederbluemle @Shadoninja: with `mode-mouse on` use can still select text with **_Shift + mouse drag_** or **_Option + mouse drag_** on Mac.

Comment: Note for Windows Terminal (microsoft/terminal) users, this won't work until [this](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/545) issue is fixed.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832199/tmux-set-g-mouse-mode-on-doesnt-work/33336609#33336609

Comment: `tmux -V` to see your tmux version. It would be nice to know how to do this within tmux too and if it was in the answer.

Comment: @ccpizza Shift+ mouse drag is not working for me on iterm

Comment: @humble: on Mac use **Option** + drag (as mentioned in the comment)

Comment: Not so sure but it works after trying this for me `setw -g mouse on`

Comment: After this run `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf` to make it take effect.

Comment: For anyone similarly confused: it worked for me only with `tmux` in front: `tmux set -g mode-mouse on`. Only showed up to the last 1989 lines though.

Answer (score 187):

From my .tmux.conf:

```
# Sane scrolling
set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'
```

This enables native xterm scrolling.

Comment: Can you explain what this does exactly?

Comment: This doesn't work for me on OS X...

Comment: Solution: https://gist.github.com/1297707

Comment: Check this out if you're confused about togdon's answer: http://superuser.com/questions/310251/use-terminal-scrollbar-with-tmux?lq=1   IMO, if you have only a single pane, this solution works better than the accepted answer.

Comment: Nice, but it breaks (for me) after displaying some file using the `less` command, i.e., the mouse wheel scrolling up will display N empty lines, where N=length of file displayed with `less`.

Comment: Works as expected in ubuntu. Pgup and Pgdn keys enable you to scroll. Thanks.

Comment: This is really weird. If you look at the scroll bar, it stays at the top until you start scrolling; then it shoots to the top. I am kind of glad this works, though.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#Scrolling_issues

Comment: I thought it was working at first, but in the end I had to disable it, it sometimes messes my output.

Comment: It doesn't keep the scrollback buffer after a(n) (re)attach

Comment: This does not work for multiple panes. It will scroll the main host terminal instead of the emulated terminals running inside of tmux

Comment: This works for me on OS X. For `screen` I used to do something similar in my `.screenrc` as well to achieve the same effect: `termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@`

Comment: This, no longer seem to work. When I scroll the output is missing lines and is incomplete.

Comment: For newer versions the answer below mine is the correct one.

Comment: Scroll-up gets completely broken (garbage text), with this enabled.

Answer (score 95):

For the newest tmux 2.1, to scroll with your mouse sanely, this is the right answer:

```
set -g mouse on
# sane scrolling:
bind -n WheelUpPane if-shell -F -t = "#{mouse_any_flag}" "send-keys -M" "if -Ft= '#{pane_in_mode}' 'send-keys -M' 'copy-mode -e; send-keys -M'"
```

it's not enough to just reload your .tmux.conf you need to restart your tmux, e.g. `tmux kill-server && tmux` or just quit the services that are using tmux.

taken from https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/145

Comment: the note in this answer about "not being enough to simply reload .tmux.conf helped" and exiting all tmux sessions for me (maybe kill-server would work) helped!

Comment: could you elaborate on how this works?

Comment: It appears to forward mouse events when the mouse is clicked/scrolled/etc. if the pane is in any indirect/buffered state (just copy-mode?), and the mouse is pressing a button, scrolling, etc. The last portion covers scrolling in direct mode by switching to an indirect mode first. If not for those controls, the terminal might interpret the events as history scrolling, if at all. With that said, I don't know if I've ever been able to get my pager and Vim to scroll correctly at the same time, and I've tried a bunch of the snippets going around.

Comment: you can't select and copy text with your mouse when `set -g mouse on` is enabled

Comment: @chefarov - per a comment on another answer, you can do this via `Shift+click` when you have mouse mode on.

Comment: Commands' output that's longer than the screens height, is trancated when scrolling up if `set -g mouse on` is set.

Comment: great that " hack for #macos " was ```tmux kill-server```

Answer (score 25):

In my case, just <kbd>opt</kbd> + <kbd>UpArrow</kbd> and <kbd>opt</kbd> + <kbd>DownArrow</kbd> on OSX.

Comment: @fixer1234 The question does not mention Linux at all. `tmux` can be used on OS X, too.

Comment: @slhck: Thanks.  Too bleary-eyed; astigmatism kicked in.  I had misread the tmux tag as a linux tag.

Comment: Simplest + no setup required solution!

Comment: This is what I was looking for while using the macOS Terminal.

Answer (score 20):

This worked for me:

```
vim ~/.tmux.conf
set -g mode-mouse on      ###Insert this setting with vim, then source the file.
tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

Comment: Since the version 2.1 (18 October 2015) the option should be `set -g mouse on`

Comment: +1 since this solution worked without restarting the tmux server (I had important jobs running).  I did detach and reattach to the tmux session though. Remember the change of `set -g mode-mouse on` to `set -g mouse on` appropriately as mentioned in the @naoko 's comment.

Comment: Very helpful. The sourcing of the config file was missing in other answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

This is the way I made it work, and the reasons why I think it is better than the default way.

To try it out, put all the code sections in `~/.tmux.conf`.

Step 1. Change the prefix key so you won't have to reach one bit. 'B' is seemingly a close key, but it is in the middle of the two index fingers (at 'F' and 'J', respectively). Because that shortcut is essential in tmux, C-j is much better as it involves zero hand movement (apart from hitting the key).

```
set -g prefix C-j
unbind C-b
bind C-j send-prefix
```

Step 2. 'S' (to enter copy-mode) is: 1) close (same reason as above), 2) involves the other hand (compare: the 1-2 in boxing, or the `ls` command to view files in a directory), and 3) could be thought of as mnemonic for "scroll" (although the copy-mode isn't just about scrolling).

```
bind s copy-mode
```

Step 3. The last part, the actual scrolling. 'P' and 'N' are familiar for this purpose to the Emacs users. They are close, intuitive ('P' is above 'N' on the keyboard), and mnemonic ("previous" and "next"). If you just did some scrolling in Emacs, and then go to tmux, it makes sense to have those shortcuts.

However, I found that 'I' and 'K' are even better - they are even closer than 'P' and 'N', and intuitive (for the same reason); as for mnemonics - as scrolling is such a common thing to do, mnemonics won't really matter as the shortcuts will soon bypass your brain and enter the muscle memory.

```
bind -t emacs-copy 'p' scroll-up
bind -t emacs-copy 'n' scroll-down
bind -t emacs-copy 'i' scroll-up
bind -t emacs-copy 'k' scroll-down
```

Answer (score 13):

I'd recommend giving a try to the [tmux-better-mouse-mode](https://github.com/NHDaly/tmux-better-mouse-mode) plugin to solve most of your tmux mouse related issues.

It's compatible with Tmux 2.1+ and the new `set-option -g mouse on` approach.

Comment: Thanks, this is the best solution for me. It covers all my mouse wheel bindings that I've added manually (so I don't need them anymore), and there are two killer-features that I wanted very much: `scroll-without-changing-pane` in combination with `scroll-without-changing-pane` and `emulate-scroll-for-no-mouse-alternate-buffer`. Now my tmux usage experience is way, way better.

Answer (score 12):

The only thing that works for me is putting the following in `~/.tmux.conf`

```
# Allow xterm titles in terminal window, terminal scrolling with scrollbar, and setting overrides of C-Up, C-Down, C-Left, C-Right
set -g terminal-overrides "xterm*:XT:smcup@:rmcup@:kUP5=\eOA:kDN5=\eOB:kLFT5=\eOD:kRIT5=\eOC"
```

(you may need to reboot for this to take effect)

**Update:**

I found that if you change the setting in Putty Connection > Data > Terminal-type to "putty" (used to fix some formatting issues) from "xterm" then this solution stops working.

**Update 2:**

Use this if you want "putty" as your terminal type: `set -g terminal-overrides "putty*:XT:smcup@:rmcup@:kUP5=\eOA:kDN5=\eOB:kLFT5=\eOD:kRIT5=\eOC"`

Comment: This one actually solves my scrolling problem in iPhone app as well.

Comment: The latest I tried this wasn't working any more, but this worked. Strange. `set -ga terminal-overrides ',xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'`

Answer (score 12):

I searched around a lot for this and the best solution for me works as mentioned in this detailed guide:
http://tangledhelix.com/blog/2012/07/16/tmux-and-mouse-mode/

Add these bindings in ~/.tmux.conf:

```
set -g mode-mouse on

unbind +
bind + \
  new-window -d -n tmux-zoom 'clear && echo TMUX ZOOM && read' \;\
  swap-pane -s tmux-zoom.0 \;\
  select-window -t tmux-zoom

unbind -
bind - \
  last-window \;\
  swap-pane -s tmux-zoom.0 \;\
  kill-window -t tmux-zoom
```

With the above approach implemented, you can copy from panes in a window as well by *zooming* into each pane first using **Prefix** **+**.

One important detail that was missing with the mouse mode is to press **Shift** before selecting an area to copy. This will copy it to traditional terminal buffer instead of the tmux copy buffer. (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#Scrolling_issues)

Answer (score 11):

On OSX Mojave and newer, after entering copy mode with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd>, you can do:

- <kbd>up arrow</kbd> for line up
- <kbd>down arrow</kbd> for line down
- <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>up arrow</kbd> for page up
- <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>down arrow</kbd> for page down
- <kbd>q</kbd> to quit copy mode

Answer (score 2):

The top answers already explain how to scroll. I'd like to add an option to avoid the need for scrolling: Pipe the output of long commands into `less`. less is a program to navigate through text files.

`superlongcommand | less`

Then you can use vim-like bindings (d/u) or PgUp/PgDn to scroll and `q` to exit. See [Less Cheatsheet](https://gist.github.com/glnds/8862214)

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Host</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>
mine key is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>
the default key is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>

after that its easy to navigate with vim config

Comment: What is `Host`?

Comment: `Host` can be any key you "bind" it to, In this example it is `Ctrl`

Answer (score 2):

The answers above did not work for me to enable keyboard scrolling, but [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1196683) from a different question worked:

```
bind -n Pageup copy-mode -u
bind -n S-Pageup copy-mode -u
bind -n S-Pagedown send-keys Pagedown
```

Comment: I wish authors define some mode for Shift+PageUp/Down navigation - it is usual for term emulators and it is frustrating not having such UX out of the box...

Answer (score -3):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> - to start scrolling
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> - to stop scrolling

Comment: This post is too short to be usefully answer the question. It adds very little new information to answers already posted; it says nothing about *how* to scroll (only how to change in and out of copy mode). Also, the default command prefix key combination is `Ctrl-B` (`Ctrl-A`is the default for GNU screen).

Comment: Not sure if the author of this answer even understood the question. It's unhelpful and just wrong.

Comment: I've been looking for how to stop scrolling for so long, thanks for pointing it out!