# Scroll shell output with mouse in tmux

Tags: shell, tmux

Mouse scrolling doesn't work in [tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux) the way it works when I run shell without tmux (in Gnome Terminal). It seems tmux sends mouse scroll events as if I pressed Up/Down keys. But I want it to scroll though the shell *output* history. Is there a way to make tmux work like this?

**Note:** I know how to scroll with the keyboard (thanks to [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/209437/how-do-i-scroll-in-tmux) here).

I tried mouse scrolling in two versions of tmux:

- 0.8-5hardy1 (on [Ubuntu 8.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_8.04_LTS_.28Hardy_Heron.29) (Hardy Heron))
- 1.3-1 (on [Ubuntu 10.10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_10.10_.28Maverick_Meerkat.29) (Maverick Meerkat))

Comment: I think bukzor's answer solves your problem for tmux 1.5 and newer.

Comment: On tmux 2.1 and above, add `set -g mouse on` to `~/.tmux.conf`, and start new tmux/tmate session. **To copy text - hold Shift key** while selecting with the mouse.

Comment: it said to me `ambiguous option mouse`. How do I fix this? I am trying to set mouse on from a remote hpc...

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72147360/how-does-one-set-the-mouse-on-a-remote-hpc

Answer (score 397):

To scroll within history of the output You would use `^b` + `[` 
You can then use M+V to page up and ^V to page down. I don't know if You can use the real <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDown</kbd> though. My terminal does not send these keys to the tmux. Instead it scrolls itself and not the tmux history.

To exit the copy mode, press ESC

To use your mouse in this mode (called copy mode) press `^b` + `:`
and enter following:

```
setw -g mouse on
```

Note: In tmux < 2.1, the option was named `mode-mouse`, and not `mouse`

Now when You change to the copy mode you can use your mouse to scroll through it.
You can put this command in your ~/.tmux.conf if You want so it loads every time You run tmux.

*Update:* As of tmux 1.5 this option makes using the scroll wheel automatically switch to copy mode and scroll back the tmux scrollback buffer. It is not necessary to first hit `Ctrl-B` + `[` any more. Scrolling back down to the prompt also ends copy mode automatically.

Comment: Note that you may have to reload the config file if you already have a running tmux server. http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/reloading-tmux-config/  tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf

Comment: Not working for me on OS X.

Comment: @Ain - There are now 11 major versions of OS X.  Which version are we talking about exactly?

Comment: The latest, 10.10.4.

Comment: For tmux >= 2.1, see @DannyRe's answer (currently quite far down).

Comment: `set -g mouse on` worked for me on macOS tmux 2.1

Comment: This setting works for ubuntu 18.04, is there any way to make it permanent

Comment: Worked on my Ubuntu

Comment: Unfortunately, marking something with the mouse does not copy it to clipboard anymore.

Comment: How do you stop it being in 'scroll' mode?

Comment: @TommyLees & Pavlo: I had to hit "q" to exit scroll mode.

Comment: set -g mouse on  disables ability to copy-paste with the mouse, at least select/right click no longer works

Comment: On Arch Linux the option can be set systemwide in `/etc/tmux.conf`.

Comment: what does `^b + [` mean in mac os X?

Comment: it said to me `ambiguous option mouse`. How do I fix this? I am trying to set mouse on from a remote hpc...

Comment: I felt like I got freedom once I knew this trick. This was answered back in 2010 and I had to find it after 12 years in 2022. What is stopping the installer to set this as default option?

Answer (score 154):

There are some changes for Tmux 2.1

- Mouse-mode has been rewritten.  There's now no longer options for:

  - mouse-resize-pane
  - mouse-select-pane
  - mouse-select-window
  - mode-mouse

  Instead there is just one option:  'mouse' which turns on mouse support
  entirely.

That would be

```
set -g mouse on
# to enable mouse scroll, see https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/145#issuecomment-150736967
bind -n WheelUpPane if-shell -F -t = "#{mouse_any_flag}" "send-keys -M" "if -Ft= '#{pane_in_mode}' 'send-keys -M' 'copy-mode -e'"
```

Comment: Thanks, now selecting panes, etc work, but scrolling doesn't. In order to make scrolling work again, use this: https://github.com/NHDaly/tmux-scroll-copy-mode

Comment: awesome - this even works on cygwin - tmux on WINDOWS 7

Comment: @Mahdi This seems to not work on osx. Any hints?

Comment: @SolidSnake: I don't remember facing any issues using that plugin. It worked smoothly, I enabled mouse mode and then installed it. You should reload your tmux config using `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf`

Comment: `bind` doesn't seem to be necessary anymore on tmux 2.3

Comment: +1 for `set -g mouse on` . Previous comment is correct. The bind is no longer needed.

Comment: this works but causes the `less`output of `git diff`  to not scroll with the mouse wheel (vim has no issue)

Comment: -1 for ```set -g mouse on``` -  disables ability to copy-paste with the mouse, at least select/right click no longer works

Comment: it said to me `ambiguous option mouse`. How do I fix this? I am trying to set mouse on from a remote hpc...

Answer (score 75):

The current version of tmux (1.5) lets you simply set the mode-mouse option on, and allows you to scroll with the mouse wheel.

```
         mode-mouse [on | off]
                 Mouse state in modes.  If on, the mouse may be used to
                 enter copy mode and copy a selection by dragging, to
                 enter copy mode and scroll with the mouse wheel, or to
                 select an option in choice mode.
```

In my .tmux.conf:

```
set-window-option -g mode-mouse on
```

**update** - as of tmux 2.1 this option has been renamed to simply `mouse`

Comment: That is the behaviour you really want! Mouse scroll enabling copy mode, not just scrolling the shell alternate buffer. That was finally the incentive to switch from _screen_ to _tmux_ for me. Is there an option to get the same behaviour also with Shift+PgUp?

Comment: @kynan: I personally just press `C-A PgUp` to do that. You can bind the page-up key directly with `tmux bind-key -n PPage copy-mode -u`. The similar thign should work for shift+pageup if you un-bind it from your local terminal.

Comment: This results in an odd behaviour where, when I scroll back to the command line, I get an extra character inserted into the CLI, which usually results in my first command being malformed. It's pretty annoying.

Comment: Note that, however this works fine for triggering the scroll with the mouse, it causes odd behavior when selecting text to be pasted with middle-click. I ended up preffering C-b pg-up/down (the default) since the tradeoff was not acceptable.

Comment: @ChrisR I get this quite a bit too and it isn't quite consistent. Is it a [M [M#[M  [M#[M  [M#[M  [M#[M  type of string?

Comment: Yeah this works for tmux 1.8 on CentOS 7.9. tmux version on CentOS 7 are bit old.

Comment: it said to me `ambiguous option mouse`. How do I fix this? I am trying to set mouse on from a remote hpc...

Comment: @CharlieParker You're using the older version of tmux, sounds like. You can upgrade or use the older version of John L. Jegutanis' answer

Answer (score 71):

Update:

Like others mentioned, in the newer tmux versions, you need to simply put the following in your .tmux.conf

```
setw -g mouse on
```

Previous recommendation for older tmux versions:

Try this in your .tmux.conf

```
# Make mouse useful in copy mode
setw -g mode-mouse on

# Allow mouse to select which pane to use
set -g mouse-select-pane on

# Allow xterm titles in terminal window, terminal scrolling with scrollbar, and setting overrides of C-Up, C-Down, C-Left, C-Right
set -g terminal-overrides "xterm*:XT:smcup@:rmcup@:kUP5=\eOA:kDN5=\eOB:kLFT5=\eOD:kRIT5=\eOC"

# Scroll History
set -g history-limit 30000

# Set ability to capture on start and restore on exit window data when running an application
setw -g alternate-screen on

# Lower escape timing from 500ms to 50ms for quicker response to scroll-buffer access.
set -s escape-time 50
```

Taken from http://brainscraps.wikia.com/wiki/Extreme_Multitasking_with_tmux_and_PuTTY

Comment: +1 for `escape-time` setting

Comment: For anyone else wondering, the .tmux.conf file is placed in your home directory.

Comment: Replace mouse settings with just `set -g mouse on`

Comment: This was working great for me on Ubuntu 18.04LTS until May 2020, then started giving me warnings and all sorts of things not working.  I guess something upgraded itself??  It seems better if I remove the mouse options, replace with `set -g mouse on` (q.v. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33336609/303056 ) and remove `terminal-overrides`

Answer (score 16):

Someone (from a source I lost) suggested adding the following to `~.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'
```

I have no idea how it works or what it does, but this now allows me to scroll with the mouse wheel inside a tmux session without having to enter tmux's copy mode; I just scroll the wheel and BAM! it works. Note that I'm using terminal.app, but I remember the OP gave the answer specifically for use with `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: Jed, thank you! Your advice works in gnome-terminal too. I will try to use this setup for some time.
But it has a disadvantage: mouse scrolling now doesn't work as expected in `less`. If I load `less` inside `tmux`, mouse scrolling doesn't scroll the file opened in `less`. It scrolls the whole terminal.
Strangely, `vim` behaves as expected inside `tmux` with your setup.

Comment: Note that as of tmux 1.5 this is superseded by the `setw -g mode-mouse on` option, which does copy mode scrollback using the mouse wheel.

Comment: The explanation is that this option disables the scroll lock on the terminal's alternate screen, which is desirable in most cases since applications requesting the alternate screen buffer (vi, less, tmux etc.) provide their own scrolling capabilities. Overriding this lock in tmux allows scrolling _the terminal's alternate screen buffer_ which doesn't give the desired result in all but a few cases. See [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/321233/44469) for a quote from `man xterm` explaining alternate screen.

Comment: Alas, this doesn't work in iTerm

Comment: I've had positive results with this in iTerm 2

Comment: This worked for me as well using Terminal.app.

Comment: it mess up the screen if you have multiple panels...

Comment: Not working with tmux on OS X (Yosemite), scrolls the whole window.

Comment: @Ain: I think yosemite changed the default, but you can switch it back under terminal preferences->Profiles->Keyboard->"Scroll Alternate Screen". Or you can hold the shift key while scrolling instead.

Comment: It does not work in my case (bash inside of Visual Studio Code). I still need to enter copy mode to scroll output in tmux.

Answer (score 14):

If you are already in a tmux session you can run the command

```
set mouse on
```

Reminder: to run commands, use your prefix then `:`.

Answer (score 7):

tmux 2.1 introduces new mouse binds.

I wrote these binds just now today. It seamlessly binds mouse wheel to arrows when not in Vim, because Vim is capable of interpreting the raw mouse wheel codes (for purposes such as choosing which Vim window to scroll for you depending on which one your mouse is over).

This means we can finally use the mouse only to view multiple man pages and whatever else accepts arrow keys. You may extend and chain the `if` logic as necessary to implement more logic for your applications.

```
bind -n WheelUpPane if "[[ #{pane_current_command} =~ vim ]]" "select-pane -t = ; send-keys -M" "select-pane -t = ; send-keys Up"
bind -n WheelDownPane if "[[ #{pane_current_command} =~ vim ]]" "select-pane -t = ; send-keys -M" "select-pane -t = ; send-keys Down"
```

With this new wheel binding capability it is possible to script the mouse wheel to do any context sensitive behavior that you like.

Comment: I'm now just sort of toying with the idea of making mousewheel on pane border do something interesting. Probably what I'll do is not map wheel on border but map it to cycle the tmux windows when done over the statusline.

Comment: What's the link to your Github? I'd like to keep abreast of your efforts! Another feature I am looking for is to have double-click copy the word to the X clipboard, like it does outside of Tmux.

Comment: @joeytwiddle I highly recommend https://github.com/NHDaly/tmux-better-mouse-mode, see my other answer

Answer (score 4):

None of the other answers worked entirely for me in themselves. I had to enable the mouse option, using `set -g mouse on` and then used `Shift + Mouse Wheel` to scroll through the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Gnome-terminal does some neat trickery translating mouse scroll events to Up and Down arrow keys in conditions of restricted "usual" scrolling. For example, when you view some text using `less` (this happens in particular when you're reading a man), you can scroll the content using `j`, `k`, and arrow keys. But *also*, with `gnome-terminal`, you can do that with mouse scrolling, thanks to the mentioned trick.

So I guess `tmux` does some "capturing" of the terminal just like `less` - and the same mechanism in `gnome-terminal` kicks in: mouse scrolling translates into Up/Down arrow key presses.

You can turn this feature off in profile settings and get the regular scrolling in any circumstances. Just unmark the last checkbox in the "scrolling" tab: [image: the checkbox].

Comment: Thank you for explanation, uldtko! But it doesn't help with the mouse scrolling problem. Yes, with the option turned off, `gnome-terminal` stops sending triple `^[[A` and `^[[B` on mouse-scroll. It's nicer in `tmux` (no ugly `^[[A^[[A^[[A` in some programs, no ugly command-history-scrolling), but now `less` stops scrolling on mouse-scroll.

Comment: Ukranian? (guessing by the `i` characters)

Answer (score 3):

The following worked fine for me even for a current session which I detached.

```
tmux set-option mouse on
```

After that attach to your session again.

```
tmux attach -t 0
```

Comment: Or `tmux set-option mode-mouse on` for old versions of tmux.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/NHDaly/tmux-better-mouse-mode

Configurable and feature-rich implementation of mouse control for newer tmuxes. highly recommended.

You likely want to use

```
set -g @emulate-scroll-for-no-mouse-alternate-buffer "on"
```

with it also.

Comment: I installed this but am no longer able to highlight and copy text with the mouse. Are you able to do this?

Comment: Yes you likely have other mouse related tmux config present that conflicts with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Warp, and I solved this issue with

Warp Settings > Features > Enable Mouse Reporting.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

With mouse mode on and mapping the mouse wheel with Up/Down keys works pretty nice.
Note: Reverse bindings if you don't like natural scroll.

```
set -g mouse on
bind -n WheelUpPane if -t = "test $(echo #{pane_current_command} |grep -e 'vim' -e 'man' -e 'less')" "select-pane -t = ; send-keys Up Up Up"  "if-shell -F -t = '#{?mouse_any_flag,1,#{pane_in_mode}}' 'send-keys -M' 'select-pane -t = ; copy-mode -e; send-keys -M'"
bind -n WheelDownPane if -t = "test $(echo #{pane_current_command} |grep -e 'vim' -e 'man' -e 'less')" "select-pane -t = ; send-keys Down Down Down"  "if-shell -F -t = '#{?mouse_any_flag,1,#{pane_in_mode}}' 'send-keys -M' 'select-pane -t = ; copy-mode -e; send-keys -M'"
```

Comment: kudos to @stealz for the solution. I just adapted a little - see it as a report cause his had a negative vote, and I could not vote yet.

Answer (score -1):

You can combine the binding ideas from the other answers to get a pretty satisfying scrolling behavior:
works in vim
changes to copy mode automatically in terminal and exits it when you reach the bottom
still allows you to use your mousewheel in man, less and journalctl.

My code:

```
bind -n WheelUpPane if -t = "test $(echo #{pane_current_command} |grep -e 'man' -e 'less' -e 'journalctl')" "select-pane -t = ; send-keys Up Up Up Up"  "if-shell -F -t = '#{?mouse_any_flag,1,#{pane_in_mode}}' 'send-keys -M' 'select-pane -t = ; copy-mode -e; send-keys -M'"
bind -n WheelDownPane if -t = "test $(echo #{pane_current_command} |grep -e 'man' -e 'less' -e 'journalctl')" "select-pane -t = ; send-keys Down Down Down Down"  "if-shell -F -t = '#{?mouse_any_flag,1,#{pane_in_mode}}' 'send-keys -M' 'select-pane -t = ; copy-mode -e; send-keys -M'"
```

you can add other commands that require arrow keys for scrolling in the grep -e 'man' part

i added the send-keys multiple times, so one tick on the mousewheel will scroll 4 lines at a time