# What does Terminal app's "Show Alternate Screen" do? (OS X)

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-lion, terminal.app

Today, I discovered a menu item called "Show Alternate Screen" in Terminal.app. I am just curious about what it does. It seems to be sharing the same shell process (unlike tabs), since I see output from one screen on the other while a command is running (e.g. `find .`) and the current directory is kept in sync.

What is this feature and how is it useful?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The alternate screen is a concept that goes way back.

From the `xterm` man page:

> In  VT102  mode, there are escape sequences to activate and
>   deactivate an alternate screen buffer, which is the same
>   size as the display area of the  window.   When  activated,
>   the current  screen is saved and replaced with the alternate
>   screen.  Saving of lines scrolled off the top of the window
>   is disabled until the normal screen is restored.  The
>   `termcap(5)` entry for xterm allows the visual editor `vi(1)`
>   to switch to the alternate screen for editing and to restore
>   the screen on exit.  A popup menu  entry  makes  it  simple
>   to  switch between the normal and alternate screens for cut
>   and paste.