# tmux - How to NOT automatically exit copy mode when scrolling down?

Tags: tmux

This question ( [Scroll shell output with mouse in tmux](https://superuser.com/questions/210125/scroll-shell-output-with-mouse-in-tmux) ) already answers the base question of how to mouse-scroll UP in tmux, but this method also automatically exits copy mode once it detects a scroll down past the current screen. According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/217269/13915) this is expected behavior too!

This is very disorienting as you're brought right back to the bottom of your prompt once you scroll down, and is not the behavior I'm looking for. Is there any way to disable this?

Comment: I do not see this behavior here. Which version of tmux and what terminal are you using?

Comment: @Thor I see this both in tmux 1.3 and 1.6, using iTerm2. I've updated the question to make it more clear - I think you should be seeing the same behavior. It's best to have a scrollback buffer of > 2 screens to see what I mean.

Comment: I see what you mean now, and I can reproduce with Iterm on OSX and rxvt-unicode on GNU/Linux. I don't think this is expected behavior, and might be a bug. The answer you refer to says that tmux should go out of copy-mode when the prompt is reached, at least to me, that means scroll all the way down first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in the latest version of tmux (1.7). You can get it from http://tmux.sourceforge.net/