# Bind keys for scrolling pages in copy mode in tmux

Tags: linux, shell, tmux

I'd like to be able to map emacs keys (like `C-v`/`M-v`) for scrolling in tmux instead of default `PgUp`/`PgDown`, is that possible? Can't see that from the manual at the moment (apologies if its there, seems like a such a natural thing considering the rest of the emacs-like navigation key bindings tmux uses)

Comment: Check out [this](http://superuser.com/a/610507/106960).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, the `emacs-copy` key binding table has all of C-v, Page Down (`NPage`), and Space bound to `page-down` as well as both M-v and Page Up (`PPage`) bound to `page-up`.

You can check your bindings with `tmux list-keys -t emacs-copy | grep -i page`.

If these bindings are missing you can reestablish them by hand (e.g. in your `~/.tmux.conf`):

```
bind-key -t emacs-copy C-v page-down
bind-key -t emacs-copy M-v page-up
```

But since these are the default, you will need to track down where they are being changed/removed before you will know where to put the above commands to make them effective (they will need to come after whatever else is modifying the bindings).

Are you sure your `mode-keys` option is set to `emacs`? It does default to `emacs`, but *tmux* will set it to `vi` (along with `status-keys`) if you have the VISUAL environment variable set and its value has `vi` in it<sup>†</sup>, or if you do not have VISUAL set but do have EDITOR set and its value has `vi` in it.

You can check your global `mode-keys` value with `tmux show-options -g -w | grep mode-keys`. You may also have a per-window `mode-keys` value (omit the `-g` to check its value; you may use `-t` to target another window if you can not run the command in the window itself).

If you want to override the “auto-detection” and always use the `emacs` binding tables, then you can put these lines in your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g status-keys emacs
set-option -gw mode-keys emacs
```

---

<sup>†</sup> The “has `vi` in it” test is actually more like “`vi` occurs after the last `/` (or anywhere if there `/` does not occur in the value)”. This means that a value like `/opt/vital/bin/emacs` will not count as `vi` (despite the `vi` in `vital`).

Comment: It sounds like you want to do this: `bind-key M-v copy-mode -u`. Then you can type two keystrokes («Prefix» «M-v») to enter `copy-mode` one page up from the end. Check out the (non-table) bindings for `PPage`: `tmux list-keys | grep -F page`. There is no binding for `NPage` though (it does not make sense to go “down” in history because you are always at the bottom of history unless you are already in `copy-mode`; similarly there can be no sensible binding for C-v

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot again! Sure totally makes sense to not have "down" bindings