# Scroll in tmux but don't enter copy mode?

Tags: tmux

I'm using iTerm2 and tmux (from homebrew) on a Mac. I have `set -g mode-mouse on` in my `tmux.conf`. When I scroll up I am automatically put into copy mode but I am looking for a way to be able to scroll normally, without going into copy mode. I don't like the scrolling and most of the time I am not intending to copy anything anyway.

Comment: See this question for http://superuser.com/q/209437/138254 options

Answer (score 1):

As of `tmux 1.8`, it offers special integration with `iTerm2`. All you need to do is start a  new tmux session with

```
tmux -CC
```

Then simply re-attach with

```
tmux -CC attach
```

Once started this way, it will look entirely native and scrolling will work as usual.

Official [`iTerm2 + tmux` integration page](http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/wiki/TmuxIntegration) details the use. Note that the information is a bit stale, as of `tmux 1.8` this support is builtin so no need to build a custom tmux version.

[tmux man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tmux) provides more information on the `-CC` flag, search for "control mode".

Comment: Updated link: https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/wikis/TmuxIntegration