# Common tmux scrolling solutions are not working

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, mouse, tmux, scrolling

I have the following in my .tmux.conf file:

```
set -g mode-mouse on
set-window-option -g mode-mouse copy-mode
set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'
```

In all running sessions, I used `C-b :source-file` to source this file, and also tried detaching and re-attaching, as well as killing sessions and just launching new ones.

Regardless, at my xterm terminal prompt within an attached session, scrolling with the mouse wheel produces things like this:

```
user@host ~ $ `H)`H)aH)aH)
```

and scrolling does not occur.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I am using MobaXterm to access a terminal from a Windows machine (this unfortunately cannot be changed). I am using tmux version 1.6.

I've already looked at the following links for solutions to this problem, and none were able to offer any help or clarifying remarks.

- < https://blogs.oracle.com/samf/entry/smcup_rmcup_hate >
- < [How do I scroll in tmux?](https://superuser.com/questions/209437/how-do-i-scroll-in-tmux) >
- < https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798103/how-to-enable-scrolling-in-tmux-panels-with-mouse-wheel >
- < https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411543/how-to-fix-scroll-bug-in-tmux >

Answer (score 3):

The default scrollback mode is copy-mode, which is activated by `ctrl-b [` by default.  After typing that you can page up and page down and use arrow keys to scroll back.

I don't have any experience trying to make the mouse do it.  But the copy-mode stuff *does* work, I use it all the time.

The tricky bit is when you leave yourself in copy mode and don't realize it.  You can hit `q` to exit it.  I've started cursing at my non-responsive window more than once, only to realize I left tmux in copy mode.

Comment: After pressing ```ctrl + b [``` you can easily scroll by pushing ctrl and using up and down arrows.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this problem for a long time as well. Most of the tips I read online didn't help, until I used this.

Put this in .tmux.conf:

```
set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'
```

Comment: I mentioned that I tried this and it did not work. It is listed directly in my question above.

Comment: Frustrating when people don't read or ignore content in your question.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue for a while and nothing worked but then I finally managed to solve it. I am using MobaXterm from a Windows machine and tmux version 2.6. I created the following `~/.tmux.conf` file:

```
set-option -g mouse on
set -g mouse on
set-window-option -g mouse on

# Start copy mode when scrolling up
bind -n WheelUpPane copy-mode

#Sane scrolling
set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'
```

Then I sourced this file in a usual session (not in tmux session):

```
tmux source ~/.tmux.conf
```

After that, scrolling up with a mouse wheel (without pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>) worked well in all tmux sessions (it makes tmux enter the copy mode).

Comment: `source` is a must.

Answer (score 0):

Hate to revive an old question, but in case anyone else is wondering in the future.

http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download-home-edition.html

Version 8.2 (2015-09-12)
Improvement: you can now scroll in Tmux using Shift+MouseWheel if you have the "set-window-option -g mode-mouse on" feature enabled in your ".tmux.conf" file.