# tmux mouse mode and scrolling very unstable - garbage printed

Tags: linux, mouse, tmux, scrolling

I am using (or trying to) tmux on Linux Mint 15 via byobu.

I am finding the mouse mode very hard to use since most of the time instead of counting it as a click, the terminal prints out random garbage as below

```
karthikt@gondor:~/vagrant 
#+ +#+ +#+ +#+ +#C6`6`6 6#6 +#+ +#+ +#+ +#+ +#+ +#+ +#+ +#+ +#+ +#+ ,#+ +#+ +#
```

This was me trying to select the other pane i think.

After looking at many other issues I have tried to fix it by turning `utf` mode off and on both. They seemed to work for a while but the issue is back worse than ever. Other solutions also do not help.

The relevant lines of my tmux conf are

```
setw -g mode-mouse on 

set -g mouse-select-pane on
set -g mouse-select-window on
set -g mouse-resize-pane on

set mouse-utf8 on

# from http://superuser.com/a/326592/160502
# "I don't know what it does, but it is pure genius. Finally, tmux scrolling works, yay!"
set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'
```

I left that comment in there to illustrate the frustration...

Please help. It is real disappointing that this works perfectly on my work mac, but not on my home Linux box.

Comment: What terminal emulator do you use?

Comment: @scicalculator guake/mate terminal

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that tmux does not support scrolling in some terminal emulators such as guake [see here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6745/scrollability-of-text-when-using-tmux). I use xterm, which tmux can handle natively. When you run the `tmux terminal-override` given in your question, you are forcing the xterm variant.

The reason this works on your work mac is because OSX supports comes with xterm, which is the default terminal emulator on that platform.

You should be fine with that terminal-override command, or you could try to use xterm or another compatible command.