# tmux mouse passthrough mode?

Tags: mouse, tmux

How do you make mouse-wheel scrolling in `tmux` work with programs such as `less` and `man`? It will work properly with `emacs` and `vi`/`vim` in xterm mouse mode, but `less` doesn't.

**EDIT**

Is there a way to have tmux pass through all mouse input to the program running in the session? e.g. clicking and dragging would go to the running program (like vim) instead of entering copy-select mode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass mouse events through tmux](https://superuser.com/questions/989505/pass-mouse-events-through-tmux)

Answer (score 0):

I just tested tmux with less, vim and man on OS X 10.11 and Ubuntu 15.04. 
By default they all accept mouse scroll. Even connected via the terminal they work.
Try sudo apt-get update.
But if vim works, then the signal is getting to the app from the mouse.

Comment: What is your tmux configuration for OS X/macOS?