# How do I get mouse scroll in less to work in iTerm2 like it does in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, scrolling, iterm2

On macOS Ventura, on a MacBook Air, with a fresh user account and default settings, in Terminal.app, I can run `man less` and then use my trackpad to scroll *down* the manpage -- equivalent to hitting `j` or down arrow.

In iTerm.app (3.4.18), `man less` displays the manpage, but "Mouse Reporting" does not become checked in the Session -> Terminal State menu, so scrolling with the trackpad down the page does nothing, and up goes into the terminal scrollback. Running `man less | less --mouse` activates mouse reporting, and I get the desired behavior (what happens in Terminal.app).

I believe that Terminal.app might be doing some magic to activate mouse capture for `less` without the additional explicit option. How does this work (i.e. what's different between the two shell instances), and how can I get the same behavior from iTerm.app?

One solution is to add `export LESS='--mouse'` to my `.zshrc`, but this doesn't answer my question of why I don't need this in Terminal.app.

Comment: I believe the beginning of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/990887/432690) may be relevant.

Comment: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/224390) might help. See also the answer by George Nachman in this [feature request](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/6998).

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to **Settings > Advanced** and then change the option *Scroll wheel sends arrow keys when in alternate screen mode* to *Yes*. This worked for me to fix the issue.

[image: screenshot of where the "Scroll wheel sends arrow keys when in alternate screen mode" can be found in iTerm2's settings, with the specific setting circled in red]

As mentioned in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/989505/pass-mouse-events-through-tmux/990887#990887), when you use `man` (or even just plain old `less`), `less` is opened in an alternate screen. Since `less` does not enable mouse support by default, this setting works around that by converting your scroll to pressing the up and down arrows on your keyboard.

Source: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/440527/scrolling-issue-in-vim-after-switch-to-iterm2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).