# Can't scroll tmux context by more than one line at a time

Tags: bash, terminal, tmux, osx-el-capitan

On OS-X I can't scroll in T-mux by more than one line at a time.

I have tried the following things:

- Ctrl+b then pg-up or pg-down.
- Ctrl+b then [ then pg-up or pg-down.
- Ctrl+b then shift+pg-up or shift-pg-down.
- Adding the line bind-key j page-up in ~/.tmux.conf and then using
  Ctrl+b and j to page up.

Notes:

- Ctrl+b is the correct prefix on my machine, it works for other tmux
  shortcuts.
- I have tried the changing the osx terminal preferences to include and
  exclude pg-up and pg-down keys.
- Ctrl+b then [ and up arrow or down arrow works to scroll one line at a
  time.
- I am using terminal on an OS-X machine but using ssh to connect to a
  linux box and using tmux there.

After all these attempts, I am still restricted to scrolling one line at a time which is much too slow when scrolling several hundred lines.

Comment: So what is your question again or am I missing it somewhere in your Notes section or something?

Comment: Sorry, the title didn't specify - it's now updated.

I can only scroll by one line at a time. The question is, how do I scroll by one screen at a time as you would usually expect to using some combination of pg-up or pg-down keys? None of the above methods work to achieve this.

Comment: Look over all the answers here and see if any of these answers help first and if so then this is a duplicate https://superuser.com/questions/209437/how-do-i-scroll-in-tmux. Otherwise just in case this has something the other doesn't mention, give it a quick peek too just in case, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81540/how-can-i-page-up-or-down-in-tmux-with-terminal-app