# Powershell is cutting off long output when connected to a terminal via SSH

Tags: ssh, terminal, powershell

I'm connected to a Linux terminal using Powershell and ssh.

When I run a command which has more than about 1 window worth of output, the output is cut off. Meaning I only see the last n lines. Is there a way to increase that buffer size or a way to scroll inside the terminal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use SSH interactively, with tty allocation and interactive shell on the server side, then server-side solutions will work for you. Possibilities:

- pipe to a pager (e.g. instead of `ls -l` invoke `ls -l | less` or maybe `ls -l --color=yes | less -r`);
- use terminal multiplexer that can scroll through history ([`tmux`](https://superuser.com/q/209437/432690) or [`screen`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40242/108618)).

Comment: I'm not familiar with Windows. I hope other answer(s) will cover client-side solutions.

Comment: piping to less works well. The only problem I could imagine is when I don't realize that there are some lines missing in the first place.