# Scroll pages with "screen" in a putty window

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux, gnu-screen

I am connected with Windows `putty` to a Linux computer, and inside this SSH session, I use `screen` (similar tu `tmux`).

I know that, in order to scroll with <kbd>PG-UP</kbd> / <kbd>PG-DOWN</kbd>, one has to do this before:

<kbd>CTRL+A</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>

This is not very handy.

**Is there a way to configure `screen` to have something like <kbd>SHIFT + PG-UP</kbd> / <kbd>SHIFT + PG-DOWN</kbd> to scroll pages (or mouse scrolling)?** (without having to do <kbd>CTRL+A, [</kbd>)

Without `screen` it's just as easy as doing <kbd>SHIFT + PG-UP</kbd> / <kbd>SHIFT + PG-DOWN</kbd>.

Note: With `tmux`, this might be the solution: [How do I scroll in tmux?](https://superuser.com/questions/209437/how-do-i-scroll-in-tmux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/165810/137396

In your local `.screenrc` file on you Linux host (probably in home directory) add the following:

```
bindkey "^[[5;2~" eval "copy" "stuff ^b"
bindkey "^[[6;2~" eval "copy" "stuff ^f"
```

This should bind <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp,</kbd> / <kbd>PgDn</kbd> via copy mode. To escape from copy mode use <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

Comment: I used the solution in the link you provided: PG UP / PG DOWN works, but not SHIFT PG UP / SHIFT PG DOWN from my Putty / SSH terminal. Not a big deal, PG UP / DOWN is already great!

Comment: I modified the code in my answer to add Shift, did it not work? The code I provided is untested in fairness as I'm not in front of a PC

Comment: It does not seem to work with SHIFT, but not a big deal, it is great with PG UP / PG DOWN!